# regexp for hashtag/mention in href

Tags: regex, formatting, hashtag, mention

My goal make html hastag, for this i'm need wrap text with # into

`<a class="tag"><span class="hash">#</span>text</a>`

I wan't make regexp which can give me words with # and @, but i'm have some trouble with URLs like this:
http://gitlab.com/#xxx or https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy

My example string:

```html
<p>Some text <span class="highlighted">#test</span><br />
<a href="http://gitlab.com/#xxx" target="_blank" class="link">gitlab.com/#xxx</a><br />
<code>some feature</code></p>
```

My regexp is:

```css
(?!.*(<mail-link|link))#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

I get 2 matches #test and last #xxx (https://regex101.com/r/pXxIkf/1)

How i can get only test, and dont find inside the href definition?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
(?<=\>)(?:[\s]*(?:#|@))([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

**(?<=>)** Positive Lookbehind to make sure that there is `>` before the hashtag.

**(?:** start non-capturig group.

**[\s]*** there is whitespace or not.

**(?:#|@)** non-capturig group that make sure there either `# or @`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pXxIkf/2)

Comment: Try in one line, didn't work:
https://regex101.com/r/pXxIkf/4



Example:
`<p>xyz #testme_ qoq#asdfdd abc#abc <a href="#n1">zzz</a></p>`

Comment: @r1sen let me know the excpected output

Comment: 3 match:
#testme_,
#asdfdd,
#abc

@Mohammed Elhag

Comment: Can you give me example, to only #testme_? Please

Comment: I mean get only word which started from #, for example #testme_ - ok , qoq#asdfdd abc#abc - doesn't start from hashtag it's wrong we don't need this

Comment: This good, but what if we have multiple language? For example:
`абв #привет123abc_ <a href="#n1">aa</a>`